# Java Annotations not being processed correctly

Tags: java, ant, junit, annotations, jersey-client

I am encountering two separate problems which seem to be related to the compiler not processing annotations

1) Running a junit test throws an exception junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found in ....

Even though I have annotated the test methods and am using junit 4.x

```
@Test
public void testTalker() throws Exception {
```

I am using ant to build the project, however building the project in eclipse using the same libraries results in the junit working.

2) Jersery WebResource Builder (com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.Builder) not being able to parse incoming xml response into the appropriate object

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", namespace="http://software.com/api", propOrder = {
"credentials",...})

@XmlRootElement(name = "tsResponse",namespace="http://software.com/api")

public class TsResponse {
    protected CredentialsType credentials;

    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "credentials",
             namespace="http://software.com/api",
             propOrder = { "site", "user" }
    )

    public class CredentialsType {
```

This xml

```
<tsResponse xmlns="http://software.com/api" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://software.com/api http://software.com/api/api-2.0.xsd">
  <credentials token="...">
    <site id="..." />
    <user id="..."/>
  </credentials>
</tsResponse>
```

is the response for this operation

```
TsResponse resp = builder(rurl).post(TsResponse.class, req);
```

However, the resulting object does not have the credentials object populated. Again it works when building with eclipse.

Is this related to annotations or is it a red herring?

Comment: I wonder if a compiler option is somehow stripping the @Annotations?